# RAM Consumption in MongoDB via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hadoop, mongoose, gps

Hi I am new to aggregation in Mongo DB. My requirement is to save The device GPS data send to the Server into my mongoDB collection namely GPS data. Currently my schema for the GPS data using Mongoose is as follows

```
  SerialNo:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        index:true
   },

  Loc: {
        type: [Number], // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
        index: '2d',// create the geospatial index
        required:true
  },

  Time:{
         type:Date
 },


  Speed:{
            type:Number,
            default:0.0                
 },      

  Message_length:{
            type:Number 
 },   

  No_Satellites:{
            type:Number
  },

  Course:{
            type:Number
  },  

  Direction:{
            type:String
  },  

  gpsLocked:{
            type:Boolean
  },

  isRealTime:{
             type:Boolean           
  },

  createdAt:{
            type:Date,
            default:Date.now
  }
```

I found out that it might not be feasible for my design  so on searching a lot on mongoDB website I came across this link  [Analyzing Time Series Data Using the Aggregation Framework and Hadoop](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-2-analyzing-time-series-data-using-aggregation-framework?jmp=docs&_ga=1.164891319.984521579.1435128633) where I found that they were using a document structure similar to my requirement which is as follows

```
data:[
   {speed:NAN,time:NAN},
   {speed:NAN,time:NAN},
   {speed:NAN,time:NAN}
]
```

My main question is that If I convert my Loc and timestamp to the format mentioned above, will I save memory consumed due to indexing when I save 500 GPS data into a single document or will it be same Memory consumption due to indexing as saving 500 different documents into my collection?

Comment: It depends on what you are indexing. Could you clarify which fields you are indexing.. just the standard `_id` or other fields as well

Comment: I am Indexing my loc and serialNo as mentioned in my schema!!!!! _id is indexed by default in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are converting in to this format

```
data:[
   {Loc:NAN,time:NAN},
   {Loc:NAN,time:NAN},
]
```

Then you have to index the complete array, if you want to query with a `Loc`. This would be a [MultiKey index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/)

The overall indexing size may be higher, because in this case, mongodb has to index the document within the array. In the previous case, it only has to index the `Loc` separately.

Your queries would be efficient, if you build a compound index with `SerialNo` and the `data`.

However, your updates would be efficient as you have to only update one entry in the data.

Note that MongoDB has a limit of 16MB per document. I’m not sure how many timestamps you would want to put into a single document.